# Авторизация пользователей GWT приложения, способы реализации

Tags: gwt, java

Нет ли в GWT встроенных функций, библиотек для осуществления авторизации пользователей? Или придется самому все делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно несложно делается при помощи [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

По минимуму:

- Делаете JSP c формой логина
- Буквально в десяток строчек настраиваете xml-конфиг с одним из стандартных провайдеров учетных записей (файл, JDBC), закрывающий неавторизованный доступ к GWT-модулю и сервисам.

Comment: Обязательно ли делать структуру проекта maven?

Comment: Нет, совершенно не обязательно.

Comment: Подавляющее большинство документации и примеров написаны для maven. Ни одного примера, описывающего данный процесс от начала до конца, для начинающего не нашел. У нас имеется gwt-приложение на eclipse. Со spring'ом раньше не работал. Как же туда авторизацию прикрутить (страница регистрации и входа в систему), может кто покажет?